# From a given regular expresssion r , can we minimize a regular expression r' such that L(r)= L(r')?

Tags: automata

Please help me out for finding the solution

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really do that.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "minimizing a regular expression"? Is [this answer that says minimizing a regular expression is very hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/66563/91753) helpful?